# question about proof in Ito's formula in cadlag case

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am reading Hiroshi Kunita's lecture *[Stochastic Differential Equations Based on Levy Processes and Stochastic Flows of Diffeomorphisms](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2054-1_6)*.It proves Ito's formula for cadlag semimartingale.

[Kunita's proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2ElN.png)

The proof is concise, but I doubt that it is not correct. Right in this picture, it constructs a function r(x,y)(in the first highlight), and claims that it suffices the identity(in the second highlight), but I just found the identidy is not valid since we can not get F by the integraton of the second order derivative F'' (this will only get F' instead of F). So I think this is proof is incorrect. Did I make some mistake?

Comment: Please [avoid images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/857384) in your question and use MathJaX instead. Here is a tutorial : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doubt is justified, the Taylor polynomial with integral remainder term is
$$
F(y)=F(x)+F'(x)(y-x)+\frac12\int_0^1(1-\theta)F''(x+\theta(y-x))(y-x)^2\,d\theta.
$$
As $|1-\theta|\le 1$ on the unit interval, this omission likely has no consequences for the proof. It is reasonable to suspect that this is a late transmission error from a manuscript to the print version.